# upstart exec prevents daemon from creating pid

Tags: upstart

I have a simple upstart script that exec my daemon. When doing so, the correct pid is returned by upstart, but my daemon is not able to create the actual pid file.

```
script 
    VM=$(cat /proc/meminfo | grep MemTotal | awk '{ print $2 }')
    ulimit -v $VM
    ulimit -c unlimited
    exec $DAEMON
end script
```

If I execute $DAEMON from the command line, then everything forks and the pid file is created as expected.

Answer (score 0):

- http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/#see-the-environment-a-job-runs-in
- http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/#checking-how-a-service-might-react-when-run-as-a-job
- http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/#determining-why-your-service-fails-to-start

If you are using Ubuntu Raring/Saucy or Debian sid, you can easily install procenv to for full environmental details (as shown in the links above).